# Java Application Versioning - For Error Checking

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, jenkins, gradle

I've searched on this topic, but I can't seem to find an answer that makes it clear what I need to do.

I'm looking for a way to give our Desktop Java Apps a version number.  Each release this number would change.  For users that have an error we could then check to see what version they were on and if it is was a known issue with that release.

This could be displayed in an exception, or we could just write it to our Oracle DB when the error occurs.

I've seen some things people do in ANT, but our tools are Gradle, Mercurial, Jenkins, Eclipse IDE.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is hard to answer and greatly depends on your application. How are your users currently reporting errors?

Comment: @kuporific Thanks for the reply.  When a user encounters an error we log it to our DB.  We track; User, Error Message, Event Time, Application ID, and Stack Trace.

If there is a way, we could add a column to this Error_Log Table like App_Version... I am just wondering if this is the best way to go, and how I would do that.